# how to upload a file from my desktop via url to a web server using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, raspberry-pi

I am trying to setup an automatic file upload system on my desktop via url directly from desktop directory to a web server.

I am working on a raspberry project and what I intend doing is to be able to request a particular file locally from my desktop to be moved to a web server.

so of course  I have done a lot file uploads using ajax, but then. what I am not sure about is specifying a file path to a file already created and then automatically moving it to a web server as compared to using an html form in uploading this file.

this is what I have at the moment

```
<script>
   //form Submit
   $("form").submit(function(evt){   
      evt.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'fileUpload',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
       }
   });
   return false;
 });
</script>
```

which accepts  a file from an upload form in html

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">File Upload</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Select File </th>
      <td><input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

what I want is to be able to specify a local url to a file "probably on my desktop or documents directory" and then move it to a web server.

Please advice

Comment: You mean you want to automatically select a file and upload it, without having to choose it by hand? For that you will need a program running on your desktop which can select the file and send a HTTP request containing it automatically.. maybe it can run as a Cron job (or scheduled task in Windows). It depends - you didn't really make clear how it should decide which file to send, and when. Maybe the service needs to ask the website automatically (via another http request) for the file name it wants, and then it can upload the correct one.

Comment: yes automatically

Comment: Ok well you need to do something like the system I've just described, then. You can't do it through a browser.

Comment: alright thanks, ill look into what you explained